# jQuery Slider and Uncaught TypeError in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, typeerror

I'm a bit clueless regarding my [FullWidth Image Slider](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ElasticSlideshow/) in combination with the Openstrap Wordpress theme.

When the function is loaded, I always get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

And I guess, this has something to do with the jquery functions loaded in the openstrap theme. I already removed the `jQuery.noConflict();`, but that did not work out.

This is the link to my test site where the error occurs:
https://dillan.de/bfm/texte/

The slider is loaded with this function:

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#ei-slider').eislideshow({
                easing      : 'easeOutExpo',
                titleeasing : 'easeOutExpo',
                titlespeed  : 1200
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And this is the .js:

```
(function( window, $, undefined ) {

/*
* smartresize: debounced resize event for jQuery
*
* latest version and complete README available on Github:
* https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.smartresize.js
*
* Copyright 2011 @louis_remi
* Licensed under the MIT license.
*/

var $event = $.event, resizeTimeout;

$event.special.smartresize  = {
    setup: function() {
        $(this).bind( "resize", $event.special.smartresize.handler );
    },
    teardown: function() {
        $(this).unbind( "resize", $event.special.smartresize.handler );
    },
    handler: function( event, execAsap ) {
        // Save the context
        var context = this,
            args    = arguments;

        // set correct event type
        event.type = "smartresize";

        if ( resizeTimeout ) { clearTimeout( resizeTimeout ); }
        resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery.event.handle.apply( context, args );
        }, execAsap === "execAsap"? 0 : 100 );
    }
};

$.fn.smartresize            = function( fn ) {
    return fn ? this.bind( "smartresize", fn ) : this.trigger( "smartresize", ["execAsap"] );
};

$.Slideshow                 = function( options, element ) {

    this.$el            = $( element );

    /***** images ****/

    // list of image items
    this.$list          = this.$el.find('ul.ei-slider-large');
    // image items
    this.$imgItems      = this.$list.children('li');
    // total number of items
    this.itemsCount     = this.$imgItems.length;
    // images
    this.$images        = this.$imgItems.find('img:first');

    /***** thumbs ****/

    // thumbs wrapper
    this.$sliderthumbs  = this.$el.find('ul.ei-slider-thumbs').hide();
    // slider elements
    this.$sliderElems   = this.$sliderthumbs.children('li');
    // sliding div
    this.$sliderElem    = this.$sliderthumbs.children('li.ei-slider-element');
    // thumbs
    this.$thumbs        = this.$sliderElems.not('.ei-slider-element');

    // initialize slideshow
    this._init( options );

};

$.Slideshow.defaults        = {
    // animation types:
    // "sides" : new slides will slide in from left / right
    // "center": new slides will appear in the center
    animation           : 'sides', // sides || center
    // if true the slider will automatically slide, and it will only stop if the user clicks on a thumb
    autoplay            : false,
    // interval for the slideshow
    slideshow_interval  : 3000,
    // speed for the sliding animation
    speed           : 800,
    // easing for the sliding animation
    easing          : '',
    // percentage of speed for the titles animation. Speed will be speed * titlesFactor
    titlesFactor        : 0.60,
    // titles animation speed
    titlespeed          : 800,
    // titles animation easing
    titleeasing         : '',
    // maximum width for the thumbs in pixels
    thumbMaxWidth       : 150
};

$.Slideshow.prototype       = {
    _init               : function( options ) {

        this.options        = $.extend( true, {}, $.Slideshow.defaults, options );

        // set the opacity of the title elements and the image items
        this.$imgItems.css( 'opacity', 0 );
        this.$imgItems.find('div.ei-title > *').css( 'opacity', 0 );

        // index of current visible slider
        this.current        = 0;

        var _self           = this;

        // preload images
        // add loading status
        this.$loading       = $('<div class="ei-slider-loading">Loading</div>').prependTo( _self.$el );

        $.when( this._preloadImages() ).done( function() {

            // hide loading status
            _self.$loading.hide();

            // calculate size and position for each image
            _self._setImagesSize();

            // configure thumbs container
            _self._initThumbs();

            // show first
            _self.$imgItems.eq( _self.current ).css({
                'opacity'   : 1,
                'z-index'   : 10
            }).show().find('div.ei-title > *').css( 'opacity', 1 );

            // if autoplay is true
            if( _self.options.autoplay ) {

                _self._startSlideshow();

            }

            // initialize the events
            _self._initEvents();

        });

    },
    _preloadImages      : function() {

        // preloads all the large images

        var _self   = this,
            loaded  = 0;

        return $.Deferred(

            function(dfd) {

                _self.$images.each( function( i ) {

                    $('<img/>').load( function() {

                        if( ++loaded === _self.itemsCount ) {

                            dfd.resolve();

                        }

                    }).attr( 'src', $(this).attr('src') );

                });

            }

        ).promise();

    },
    _setImagesSize      : function() {

        // save ei-slider's width
        this.elWidth    = this.$el.width();

        var _self   = this;

        this.$images.each( function( i ) {

            var $img    = $(this);
                imgDim  = _self._getImageDim( $img.attr('src') );

            $img.css({
                width       : imgDim.width,
                height      : imgDim.height,
                marginLeft  : imgDim.left,
                marginTop   : imgDim.top
            });

        });

    },
    _getImageDim        : function( src ) {

        var $img    = new Image();

        $img.src    = src;

        var c_w     = this.elWidth,
            c_h     = this.$el.height(),
            r_w     = c_h / c_w,

            i_w     = $img.width,
            i_h     = $img.height,
            r_i     = i_h / i_w,
            new_w, new_h, new_left, new_top;

        if( r_w > r_i ) {

            new_h   = c_h;
            new_w   = c_h / r_i;

        }
        else {

            new_h   = c_w * r_i;
            new_w   = c_w;

        }

        return {
            width   : new_w,
            height  : new_h,
            left    : ( c_w - new_w ) / 2,
            top     : ( c_h - new_h ) / 2
        };

    },
    _initThumbs         : function() {

        // set the max-width of the slider elements to the one set in the plugin's options
        // also, the width of each slider element will be 100% / total number of elements
        this.$sliderElems.css({
            'max-width' : this.options.thumbMaxWidth + 'px',
            'width'     : 100 / this.itemsCount + '%'
        });

        // set the max-width of the slider and show it
        this.$sliderthumbs.css( 'max-width', this.options.thumbMaxWidth * this.itemsCount + 'px' ).show();

    },
    _startSlideshow     : function() {

        var _self   = this;

        this.slideshow  = setTimeout( function() {

            var pos;

            ( _self.current === _self.itemsCount - 1 ) ? pos = 0 : pos = _self.current + 1;

            _self._slideTo( pos );

            if( _self.options.autoplay ) {

                _self._startSlideshow();

            }

        }, this.options.slideshow_interval);

    },
    // shows the clicked thumb's slide
    _slideTo            : function( pos ) {

        // return if clicking the same element or if currently animating
        if( pos === this.current || this.isAnimating )
            return false;

        this.isAnimating    = true;

        var $currentSlide   = this.$imgItems.eq( this.current ),
            $nextSlide      = this.$imgItems.eq( pos ),
            _self           = this,

            preCSS          = {zIndex   : 10},
            animCSS         = {opacity  : 1};

        // new slide will slide in from left or right side
        if( this.options.animation === 'sides' ) {

            preCSS.left     = ( pos > this.current ) ? -1 * this.elWidth : this.elWidth;
            animCSS.left    = 0;

        }   

        // titles animation
        $nextSlide.find('div.ei-title > h2')
                  .css( 'margin-right', 50 + 'px' )
                  .stop()
                  .delay( this.options.speed * this.options.titlesFactor )
                  .animate({ marginRight : 0 + 'px', opacity : 1 }, this.options.titlespeed, this.options.titleeasing )
                  .end()
                  .find('div.ei-title > h3')
                  .css( 'margin-right', -50 + 'px' )
                  .stop()
                  .delay( this.options.speed * this.options.titlesFactor )
                  .animate({ marginRight : 0 + 'px', opacity : 1 }, this.options.titlespeed, this.options.titleeasing )

        $.when(

            // fade out current titles
            $currentSlide.css( 'z-index' , 1 ).find('div.ei-title > *').stop().fadeOut( this.options.speed / 2, function() {
                // reset style
                $(this).show().css( 'opacity', 0 ); 
            }),

            // animate next slide in
            $nextSlide.css( preCSS ).stop().animate( animCSS, this.options.speed, this.options.easing ),

            // "sliding div" moves to new position
            this.$sliderElem.stop().animate({
                left    : this.$thumbs.eq( pos ).position().left
            }, this.options.speed )

        ).done( function() {

            // reset values
            $currentSlide.css( 'opacity' , 0 ).find('div.ei-title > *').css( 'opacity', 0 );
                _self.current   = pos;
                _self.isAnimating       = false;

            });

    },
    _initEvents         : function() {

        var _self   = this;

        // window resize
        $(window).on( 'smartresize.eislideshow', function( event ) {

            // resize the images
            _self._setImagesSize();

            // reset position of thumbs sliding div
            _self.$sliderElem.css( 'left', _self.$thumbs.eq( _self.current ).position().left );

        });

        // click the thumbs
        this.$thumbs.on( 'click.eislideshow', function( event ) {

            if( _self.options.autoplay ) {

                clearTimeout( _self.slideshow );
                _self.options.autoplay  = false;

            }

            var $thumb  = $(this),
                idx     = $thumb.index() - 1; // exclude sliding div

            _self._slideTo( idx );

            return false;

        });

    }
};

var logError                = function( message ) {

    if ( this.console ) {

        console.error( message );

    }

};

$.fn.eislideshow            = function( options ) {

    if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {

        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );

        this.each(function() {

            var instance = $.data( this, 'eislideshow' );

            if ( !instance ) {
                logError( "cannot call methods on eislideshow prior to initialization; " +
                "attempted to call method '" + options + "'" );
                return;
            }

            if ( !$.isFunction( instance[options] ) || options.charAt(0) === "_" ) {
                logError( "no such method '" + options + "' for eislideshow instance" );
                return;
            }

            instance[ options ].apply( instance, args );

        });

    } 
    else {

        this.each(function() {

            var instance = $.data( this, 'eislideshow' );
            if ( !instance ) {
                $.data( this, 'eislideshow', new $.Slideshow( options, this ) );
            }

        });

    }

    return this;

};

})( window, jQuery );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is being caused by this line:

```
$(function() { // line 388
```

At this point in your code, jQuery is running in [no conflict mode](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/). This means it has renounced use of the dollar variable. AFAIK, this happens on most (all?) WordPress sites.

To solve this you can either change any occurence of `$` to `jQuery`:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#ei-slider').eislideshow({
    easing    : 'easeOutExpo',
    titleeasing : 'easeOutExpo',
    titlespeed  : 1200
  });
});
```

or pass in a reference to the dollar variable as a parameter to the anonymous function. Within the anonymous function, you can then use `$` as normal:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#ei-slider').eislideshow({
    easing    : 'easeOutExpo',
    titleeasing : 'easeOutExpo',
    titlespeed  : 1200
  });
});
```

This will make your slider work, as [this demo](http://hibbard.eu/blog/pages/full-width-slider.html) shows.

Comment: Jack, you don't believe how happy I'm. And now it's completely clear why _all_ the sliders I tried did not work. Thanks a thousand!

Comment: Of course I do. Thanks for the note, I'm here for the first time.